# Python Pandas Calculating Percentile per row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, percentile

I have the following code and would like to create a new column per Transaction Number and Description that represents the 99th percentile of each row.

I am really struggling to achieve this - it seems that most posts cover calculating the percentile on the column.

Is there a way to achieve this? I would expect a new column to be create with two rows.

```
df_baseScenario = pd.DataFrame({'Transaction Number' : [1,10],
                            'Description'      :['asf','def'],
                            'Calc_PV_CF_2479.0':[4418494.085,-3706270.679],
                            'Calc_PV_CF_2480.0':[4415476.321,-3688327.494],
                            'Calc_PV_CF_2481.0':[4421698.198,-3712887.034],
                            'Calc_PV_CF_2482.0':[4420541.944,-3706402.147],
                            'Calc_PV_CF_2483.0':[4396063.863,-3717554.946],
                            'Calc_PV_CF_2484.0':[4397897.082,-3695272.043],
                            'Calc_PV_CF_2485.0':[4394773.762,-3724893.702],
                            'Calc_PV_CF_2486.0':[4384868.476,-3741759.048],
                            'Calc_PV_CF_2487.0':[4379614.337,-3717010.873],
                            'Calc_PV_CF_2488.0':[4389307.584,-3754514.639],
                            'Calc_PV_CF_2489.0':[4400699.929,-3741759.048],
                            'Calc_PV_CF_2490.0':[4379651.262,-3714723.435]})
```

Comment: All you provided was the `DataFrame`, not any attempt at calculating this percentile yourself... Also it would be helpful if you showed a sample of your desired output.

Comment: Apologies, I am new to this and was struggling with the logic. I understand for future posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

`df['99th_percentile'] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: numpy.percentile(x, 99), axis=1)`

I'm assuming here that the variable 'cols' contains a list of the columns you want to include in the percentile (You obviously can't use the Description in your calculation, for example).

What this code does is loops over rows in the dataframe, and for each row, computes the [numpy.percentile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) to get the 99th percentile. You'll need to import numpy.

If you need maximum speed, then you can use numpy.vectorize to remove all loops at the expense of readability (untested):

```
perc99 = np.vectorize(lambda x: numpy.percentile(x, 99))
df['99th_percentile'] = perc99(df[cols].values)
```

Comment: This is excellent thank you. I initially expected the loop to be slow and thought perhaps passing a vector / matrix would be a better approach. Do you have a view on this?

Comment: @Travis The loop can introduce some delay, but this isn't more than a few seconds for a million rows. Here is a faster method:

`df['99th_percentile'] = [numpy.percentile(x, 99) for x in df[cols].values]`

which has almost no overhead, but is a bit more ugly. Check my answer edit for the fastest value I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified from @mxbi.

```
import numpy as np
df = df_baseScenario.drop(['Transaction Number','Description'], axis=1)
df_baseScenario['99th_percentile'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.percentile(x, 99), axis=1)
```